# How to remove Register link from the header and rename Log in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, login, registration, headerlink

I want to remove **Register** link from the header and rename **Log in** in Magento2.2.5?

Refer screenshot.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how's doing, i shared the answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273294/52244 which match your expected as i am assuming, if you feel and it matches your expectation please *mark as valid answer*, one more thing only asking question is not way of solving problems, once get the solutions, please shared. and mark as valid for shared answer by you or someone, hope you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

## Remove `Register Link` from header globally

Go to (assuming you cloned your theme from **LUMA theme** so this file is exist in theme)

```
...\app\design\frontend\[COMPANY]\[THEME]\Magento_Customer\layout\default.xml
```

and add

```
<referenceBlock  name="register-link" remove="true"/>
```

code inside the **body tag** (best place to add at **bottom before body close** tag)

---

## To `Rename Log In` in header globally

open `...\app\design\frontend\[COMPANY]\[THEME]\Magento_Customer\templates\account\link\authorization.phtml` file

**if not exist in theme** then copy from

`...\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account\link\authorization.phtml`

**or create empty file and paste below code**

```
<?php

$dataPostParam = '';
$custom_label = __("Log In / Register"); // Added custom text
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
    $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
    $custom_label = $block->getLabel(); 
}
?>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('or')) ?>">
    <a <?=  $block->getLinkAttributes() ?><?= $dataPostParam ?>>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($custom_label) ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Note :**  Above code copied from `...\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\account\link\authorization.phtml` and removed all comments area

---

**Note :** **[COMPANY]\[THEME]** value can replace with your company/theme

Answer (score 0):

How to customize header all link like Sign in, compare product etc.. Try with below Blog link it will explain in detail.

- [How to customize header link](https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-1-x-manage-top-header-links/)

If you want to add a custom link to the header then follow below blog link.

- [Add custom link to header](https://magenest.com/en/add-custom-header-link-magento-2/)

I hope it helps!